# finding integer solutions for a and b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Show that the only positive integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ in the equation $a^2-b^2=16$ are $a=4, b=0$ and $a=5, b=3.$ How many pairs of solutions would there be if we allowed negative values for the variables as well?

I know that $a^2-b^2=16=(a+b)(a-b)=16.$ I also know that the solutions are $(4,0)$ and $(5,3)$ because I plugged them in to find a solution. I just forgot how do you solve something like this. Can someone please show me? I suppose it is the samething with the negative values?

Comment: The negative values question should be fairly obvious since all variables in the equation are squared. Thus $\{(\pm4, 0), (\pm5,\pm3)\}$ is the solution set.

Comment: @user164587 Yes but how do you go about solving this. I just plugged in numbers.

Comment: See this [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934124).

Answer (score 3):

$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=16$
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
(a-b)&(a+b)&a&b\\\hline
1&16&8.5&7.5\\
2&8&5&3\\
4&4&4&0\\
-1&-16&-8.5&-7.5\\
-2&-8&-5&-3\\
-4&-4&-4&0
\end{array}$$

Comment: But doesn't this ignore $\begin{array}{c|c}
(a-b)&(a+b)&a&b\\\hline
8&2&5&-3\\
16&1&8.5&-7.5\\
-16&-1&-8.5&7.5\\
-8&-2&-5&3
\end{array}$?  Point being if we don't eliminate redundant similar cases we must consider *all* possible $10$ cases. (Noting $r^2-k^2 = (\pm r)^2-(\pm k)^2$ we can reduce this to $|a|-|b|, |a|+|b|$ and noting $|a|-|b|< |a|+|b|$ the reduces to only three cases. (and noting $|a|+|b|=(|a|-|b|)+2|b|$ must both be even or both odd we reduce to only two.. the considering $a=\pm|a|$ and $b=\pm|b|$ we get all 6 cases.

Answer (score 0):

$(a-b)(a+b) = 16$

$(a-b) = \frac{16}{(a+b)}$

$a = \frac{16}{(a+b)} + b$

$a = \frac{16}{(a+b)} + \frac{b(a+b)}{(a+b)}$

$a = \frac{16}{(a+b)} + \frac{ab+b^2}{(a+b)}$

$a = \frac{(16 + ab + b^2)}{(a+b)}$

$a(a+b) = 16 + ab + b^2$

$a^2 + ab - ab = 16 + ab + b^2 - ab$

$a^2 = 16 + b^2$

$a = \frac{+}{-} \sqrt{16 + b^2}$

Every negative solution of $a$ and $b$ should also have a positive solution of $a$ and $b$ since they are squared. It does not matter if $a$ is positive or negative or if $b$ is positive or negative.