# Is there an algorithm for writing an integer as a difference of squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, square-numbers

For example, if we have $36$, is there an algorithm to determine that it may equal $10^2-8^2$? What if we blow up the number to something like $492709612098$? **Can it be written as the difference of two squares?** *If so, how do we know?*

**Also, does it matter if the number in question has more or fewer factors?**

**EDIT: I WANT TO KNOW THE ALGORITHM, AND NOT WHETHER A NUMBER MAY BE WRITTEN AS SUCH. BASICALLY I WANT TO KNOW IF THERE IS AN ALGORITHM WHERE YOU CAN INPUT NUMBER $N$ AND GET THE ADDEND SQUARE NUMBER $X$.**

Comment: Maybe it's worth using the fact that $10^2-8^2 = (10+8)(10-8)$? Then you can look at the factors.

Comment: Please, avoid the extensive use of uppercase in your requests. Some may consider it rude.

Comment: I think the caps are uncalled for..

Comment: Not only are caps uncalled for, not only it is rude, your claim "I want to know the algorithm and not whether a number may be written as such" flatly contradicts the bolded part in your first paragraph.

Comment: It also makes you sound like you don't care about the maths, just want a solution - which no one will appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

Let N=ab then consider $a=c+d$ and $b=c-d$. Then $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $d=\frac{a-b}{2}$ now $N=c^2-d^2$. So the only numbers that can't be written as the difference of two squares are of the form $2K$ where K is an odd number. 
So your number $492709612098$ can't be written as a difference of two squares because $492709612098=2*246354806049$

Here is the algorithm in pseudocode

1) Write the number in the form $n=a*b$ where either $a$ and $b$ are both even or $a$ and $b$ are both odd

2) set $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $d=\frac{a-b}{2}$

3) Now $N=c^2-d^2$

Comment: See my edit. What is the ALGORITHM to determine the square number addend?

Comment: To slightly complement this answer: compute the remainder of $n$ mod 4. If that remainder is $2$, terminate the algorithm. If the remainder is $0$, write $n = 4k$, then $n = (k + 1)^2 - (k-1)^2$. Otherwise, $n$ is odd, so write it as $n = 2k + 1$, and we have $n = (k+1)^2 - k^2$

Answer (score 1):

This might answer partially your needs. One option is using Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ of the form $a^2+b^2=c^2$, there is a known formula to obtain those kind of triples. Here is the link to the explanation at the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple).

If you can generate a triple $(a,b,c)$, then you can obtain $a^2 = c^2-b^2$ or $b^2 = c^2-a^2$.

Indeed if you obtain one primitive Pithagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ such as $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then you got a whole family of Pythagorean triples $ \forall k\gt 1\,\ (ka,kb,kc)\ /$  $(ka)^2 + (kb)^2 = (kc)^2$.