# If we do not know a number's factors, what is the algorithm (if there is one) to write it as a difference of two squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, factoring, square-numbers

For example, if we have a number like 29873412895, is there an algorithm that can find it as a difference of two squares? Or must you need the factors of the numbers? And what might be the algorithm? Thanks!

Apologies for my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334290/is-there-an-algorithm-for-writing-an-integer-as-a-difference-of-squares?noredirect=1#comment2711703_1334290), in which I acted very callous.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve

Comment: It is sure that once it is written as a difference of two squares, you will have factors (though not necessarily irreducible (prime) factors).  So searching for the difference of two squares representation for a number is a factoring strategy that goes back to Fermat (at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to factorise anything. Every positive integer can be expressed as one of the following:

- $2n+1$
- $4n+2$
- $4n$

The first and third are differences of two squares:

- $2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2$
- $4n = (n+1)^2-(n-1)^2$

Numbers of the second form can't be expressed as the difference of two squares (because every square is equal to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$, so we can't subtract one from another to get $2$ mod $4$).

Answer (score 3):

If $k=2n+1$ is an odd number, then $k=(n+1)^2-n^2$. Finding other ways is esentially the same as factoring the number.

Comment: For completeness, numbers of the form $4n+2$ are not expressible as a difference of squares, and numbers of the form $4^m(2n+1)$ are $(2^m(n+1))^2-(2^mn)^2$.

Comment: @user26486: Not quite complete $-$ you are forgetting numbers of the form $2^{2m+3}(2n+1)$.