# General solution for nonlinear Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

As the title says I'm looking for a general solution to a Diophantine equation of the form:

> $y^2 = x^2 + kx - m$

Where $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers. I know that $k$ and $m$ will always be a multiple of 2 if that helps.

Here are a few examples that I solved through brute force.

> 1. $y^2 = x^2 + 30 x - 28$  
>      $x = 2$  
>      $y = 6$
> 2. $y^2 = x^2 + 474 x - 554$  
>      $x = 45$  
>      $y = 151$
> 3. $y^2 = x^2 + 1802 x - 3018$  
>      $x = 37$  
>      $y = 255$

I'm a bit of a dummy so a thorough explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you choose any values you want for $x$, $y$, and $k$ and then set    $m=x^2 + kx-y^2 $?

Comment: Unfortunately not I'm writing an algorithm that returns $y$ given $f(k, m)$

Comment: Then should I volte  to close your question because it's unclear what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Write $k=2b$. Then $y^2 = (x+b)^2 -b^2 - m$ and so $m+b^2=(x+b)^2 -y^2$ is a difference of two squares. Now use this [well-known fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547420/589), which is easy to prove:

> $N \in \mathbb Z$ is a difference of two squares iff $N$ is odd or a multiple of $4$.

To be [explicit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/934145/589), if $N=uv$ with $u$ and $v$ of the same parity, then
$$
N=uv=\left(\dfrac{u+v}2\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{u-v}2\right)^2
$$

Therefore, the general solution of $y^2 = x^2 + kx - m$ follows from factoring $N=m+(\frac k2)^2$ as two factors of the same parity and using the formula above to find $x+\frac k2$ and $y$.

Let's see how this works for your first example:
$m+b^2=28+15^2=253=11\cdot 23=17^2-6^2$. Therefore, $x+15=17, y=6$. This is the only solution.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. But factoring if I'm unlucky is a lot harder than trying different values of $x$ especially since I can trace the squares by summation of odd numbers. I forgot to specify that I'm trying to write an algorithm to solve these.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below, has parametric soution:

$y^2=x^2+kx-m$

$(x)= (2w)(p^2-6p+23)$

$(y)= (2w)(3p^2-9p-42)$

$(k)= (30w)(p^2+6p+5)$

$(m)= (28w^2)(p^2+6p+5)(p^2+14)$

Where $w=1/(p^2+14)$

For p=3  we get:

$84^2=28^2 +960(28)-20608$